# finding the Y coordinate of a dot on a linear-function straight line

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a straight line on a graph and three dots: A, B and C.

I know that dot A's coordinates are A (3,5; 5), and the dot C's coordinates are C (7; 6).

However, I only know the first coordinate of dot B: B (5; ?).

How can I find out the dot B's second coordinate?

Comment: What do the semicolons mean? Why is $A$ $3$-dimensional but $C$ is 2-dimensional, yet you claim there is a line between $A$ and $C$? Do you mean $A=(3,5)$ and $C=(7,6)$?

Comment: @Dastur I meant that A's x is 3,5 and A's y is 5. Sorry, I am not a native English speaker. I used notations accepted in my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $A,B,C$ are points on the line with the equation $y=mx+b.$

From $A$ amd $C$ we get the equations

$5=3.5m+b$ amd $6=7m+b.$

Now compute $m$ and $b$.

Then we get the second coordinate of $B$ by $?=5m+b.$